# Rails: undefined method `primary_key' for String:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 classes, Schema, Entity and Property, representing the DB design business.
The Schema-Entity seems work, but Entity-Property does not.

```
class Hx::Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schema
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :properties    ,  class_name: "Hx::Property"  , primary_key: "id"
end

class Hx::Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :destination, :indexed, :inverse, :isToMany, :kind, :name, :optional, :transient  , :type


  belongs_to :entity
end
```

When I run entity_obj.properties, it throws the error `undefined method primary_key' for String:Class`.

I twist around the has_many's options, but it does not help.

Does anyone has any idea on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you muttonlamb!

I figured out the problem.

In the beginning, I guess the problem is around `has_many` since that is where it appears. But it is not the case. even i do not define `class_name`, Rails still can find the class.

Later on I found some record show up that the attribute `type` in `Property` is not assigned a value. The root cause is that I override superclass's attribute !

The solution:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_column :hx_properties , :type, :datatype
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to drop the "" around `HX::Property`

The error message is telling you that it is trying to call primary key on an object of String:Class